# I have two little issues in my filtering and pagination code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello guys i would like you to help me fix my code so i can get it working very well.

1. when i filter the cards on the search box pagination mode puts alot of cards and i just want 9 per page...
2. i want to make the left and right arrows working very well

i hope you guys can help me with this issue, thanks <3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

  pageSize = 9;

  showPage = function(page) {
    $(".card").hide();
    $(".card").each(function(n) {
      if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
        $(this).show();
    });
  }

  showPage(1);

  $("#paginator a").click(function() {
    $("#paginator a").removeClass("pagActive");
    $(this).addClass("pagActive");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
  });

});
```

```css
.searchBar {
  background: rgb(14, 226, 14);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.searchBar>input {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card {
  background: rgb(140, 255, 140);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagination {
  background: violet;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pagination a {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a:hover {
  background: rgb(192, 91, 192);
}

.pagActive {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchBar">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="search...">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 1</h3>
      <p>description 1</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 2</h3>
      <p>description 2</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 3</h3>
      <p>description 3</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 4</h3>
      <p>description 4</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 5</h3>
      <p>description 5</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 6</h3>
      <p>description 6</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 7</h3>
      <p>description 7</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 8</h3>
      <p>description 8</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 9</h3>
      <p>description 9</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 10</h3>
      <p>description 10</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 11</h3>
      <p>description 11</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 12</h3>
      <p>description 12</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="paginator" class="pagination">
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="pagActive">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I added snippet to your question based on your code, please check if everything is correct

Answer (score 2):

To show correct amount of elements after search you can modify a bit your `showPage` method and do filtering inside.

```
showPage = function(page, searchTerm) {
   let $filteredCards = $(".card");
   if (searchTerm) { //if some search text is present, filter... if not - take all cards
     $filteredCards = $filteredCards.filter(function() {
       return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
     });
   }
   $(".card").hide();
   $filteredCards.each(function(n) {
     if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
       $(this).show();
   });
}
```

About "left-right arrows": here you can set some data attribute that will identify page number instead of taking number from text. And for "left arrow" you can set 1, for "right" - last page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    showPage(1, value);
  });

  pageSize = 9;

  showPage = function(page, searchTerm) {
    let $filteredCards = $(".card");
    if (searchTerm) {
      $filteredCards = $filteredCards.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
      });
    }
    $(".card").hide();
    $filteredCards.each(function(n) {
      if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
        $(this).show();
    });
  }

  showPage(1);

  $("#paginator a").click(function() {
    $("#paginator a").removeClass("pagActive");
    $(this).addClass("pagActive");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).data('page')), $("#myInput").val().toLowerCase());
  });

});
```

```css
.searchBar {
  background: rgb(14, 226, 14);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.searchBar>input {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card {
  background: rgb(140, 255, 140);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagination {
  background: violet;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pagination a {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a:hover {
  background: rgb(192, 91, 192);
}

.pagActive {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchBar">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="search...">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 1</h3>
      <p>description 1</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 2</h3>
      <p>description 2</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 3</h3>
      <p>description 3</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 4</h3>
      <p>description 4</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 5</h3>
      <p>description 5</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 6</h3>
      <p>description 6</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 7</h3>
      <p>description 7</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 8</h3>
      <p>description 8</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 9</h3>
      <p>description 9</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 10</h3>
      <p>description 10</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 11</h3>
      <p>description 11</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>title 12</h3>
      <p>description 12</p>
      <a href="#Link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="paginator" class="pagination">
  <a href="#" data-page="1"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="pagActive" data-page="1">1</a>
  <a href="#" data-page="2">2</a>
  <a href="#" data-page="3">3</a>
  <a href="#" data-page="4">4</a>
  <a href="#" data-page="5">5</a>
  <a href="#" data-page="6">6</a>
  <a href="#" data-page="6"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
</div>
```